# How can I scroll to a specific location in Scroll View via Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, position, scrollview

I am brand new to Kotlin/App Development {2 weeks}. Currently I have a Scroll View and I would like to go to specific locations within the scroll view.  One of my issues is I can't seem to find much Kotlin code on here.  I've tried to convert the Java but not having much success.  I'm also not sure where to put the code that I have indeed found.  This is what I have so far:

```
class AKCell : AppCompatActivity() {

public fun civilClick(view: View) {

val ascrollView = findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.ascrollView)
val textView32 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView32)

ascrollView.post(object : Runnable {
   override fun run() {
     ascrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textView32.bottom)
}

})

}
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a_k_cell)

     }
  }
```

However, when I attempt to run the code, it fails.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: how did it fail?

Comment: When I run it and click on the textView32 in the activity, (hoping it takes me to the corresponding location in scrollView), the app crashes. Screen goes white then closes

Comment: please add the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kotlin code

```
ascrollView!!.post { ascrollView!!.scrollTo(0, textView32!!.bottom) }
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but where should I be using that? I think that's part of my issue. The way the app is laid out, there's a main activity with a list of countries (activity a). Once u select a country, another activity is displayed with several options for food (activity b). Once u select the food, it goes to the scrollView (activity c) which has several categories. I want it to go to cheese or milk or whatever. Specific categories in activity c, based on what's selected in activity b. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Why dont you use RecyclerView instead of ScrollView in ActivityC, it's more convenient.

Comment: Hmmm. I will check it out. Since I'm new to this I didn't even know such a view existed!

Comment: If you have any problems, let me know

Comment: Unfortunately I am only getting a grey window with RecyclerView

Comment: how did you implement it?